# How can I sort List<T> based on properties of T?

Tags: c#, sorting, generic-list

My Code looks like this :

```
Collection<NameValueCollection> optionInfoCollection = ....
List<NameValueCollection> optionInfoList = new List<NameValueCollection>();
optionInfoList = optionInfoCollection.ToList();

if(_isAlphabeticalSoting)
   Sort optionInfoList
```

I tried optionInfoList.Sort() but it is not working.

Answer (score 26):

Using the sort method and lambda expressions, it is really easy.

```
myList.Sort((a, b) => String.Compare(a.Name, b.Name))
```

The above example shows how to sort by the Name property of your object type, assuming Name is of type string.

Comment: You could just use string.Compare(a.Name, b.Name), which would be safe?

Comment: Thanks! Learn something new everyday... I'll edit the answer.

Answer (score 8):

If you just want `Sort()` to work, then you'll need to implement `IComparable` or `IComparable<T>` in the class.

If you don't mind creating a *new* list, you can use the `OrderBy`/`ToList` LINQ extension methods. If you want to sort the existing list with simpler syntax, you can add a few extension methods, enabling:

```
list.Sort(item => item.Name);
```

For example:

```
public static void Sort<TSource, TValue>(
    this List<TSource> source,
    Func<TSource, TValue> selector)
{
    var comparer = Comparer<TValue>.Default;
    source.Sort((x, y) => comparer.Compare(selector(x), selector(y)));
}
public  static void SortDescending<TSource, TValue>(
    this List<TSource> source,
    Func<TSource, TValue> selector)
{
    var comparer = Comparer<TValue>.Default;
    source.Sort((x, y) => comparer.Compare(selector(y), selector(x)));
}
```

Comment: Do you have an example of using these extension methods, I tried using for my question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31057258/sort-list-of-dictionary-using-icomparer-instead-of-orderby, but couldn't implement the way you have suggested

Answer (score 2):

```
public class Person  {
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
}

List<Person> people = new List<Person>();

people.Sort(
    delegate(Person x, Person y) {
        if (x == null) {
            if (y == null) { return 0; }
            return -1;
        }
        if (y == null) { return 0; }
        return x.FirstName.CompareTo(y.FirstName);
    }
);
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to set up a comparer that tells Sort() how to arrange the items.

Check out [List.Sort Method (IComparer)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/234b841s.aspx) for an example of how to do this...