# Using Lambda expressions to order a list by GMT date

Tags: c#, datetime, lambda, gmt

I have a list that contains dates that are in GMT format.

What is the most elegant way to ensure that the following Lambda expression orders on the date field as GMT?

```
ProductsList.OrderBy(Product => Product.Added).ToList();
```

Comment: What do you mean by "in GMT format"? What's the type of the Added property?

Comment: Greenwich Mean Time. Added is a DateTime field retrieved from sql database. BTW I knew this question was a Jon Skeet honey trap!  LOL  ;->

Comment: How is GMT relevant? Does the `Added` property contain dates for various time zones? If they are all in the same time zone, the order will not change if you just sort by the date, or if you first convert all the dates to GMT first. I guess I am missing something here...

Comment: Hi, the Added field is DateTime originating from a database and is held as GMT but I would like to ensure that later that it is not sorted as a string instead. But I suppose by ensuring that it keeps its type as datetime when passed to the list will ensure that this will not happen.

Comment: If your added DateTime is in GMT then you shouldn't have a problem.

It'll only sort as string if you do "Product.Added.ToString()".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The inbuilt LINQ operators use the expected sort operations (for LINQ-to-Objects, it does this using `Comparer<T>.Default`. Your lambda expression is strongly typed; behind the scenes the compiler inferred some generics for you - it is actually:

```
var newList = Enumerable.OrderBy<Product,DateTime>(
         ProductsList, Product => Product.Added).ToList();
```

It already **knows** it is a `DateTime`, so the only time you'd need to do something extra here is if your dates contain a range of different timezones. Of course, *within* a timezone you should be fine, but you could (if you were paranoid) convert all to UTC - I don't **think** you need to do this in your case, but:

```
var newList = ProductsList.OrderBy(
        Product => Product.Added.ToUniversalTime()).ToList();
```

Note that this actually creates a *second* list (it doesn't change the ordering of the original list); you can use the [code from here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/605189/how-can-i-sort-listt-based-on-properties-of-t/605233#605233) to do an in-place sort using lambdas:

```
ProductsList.Sort(Product => Product.Added);
```