# Windows Phone Sqlite Order By

Tags: sqlite, windows-phone-8

I am trying to build a grouped list for a windows phone app. When I use this query I get the grouped list, but it is not sorted:

```
return await _dbConnection.QueryAsync<Employee>(
    "SELECT * FROM Employee WHERE Active = 1");
```

When I try to add an order by clause, I get zero results:

```
return await _dbConnection.QueryAsync<Employee>(
    "SELECT * FROM Employee WHERE Active = 1 ORDER BY FirstName");
```

I know "FirstName" is the correct column name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you get an enumerable list from your `QueryAsync` method, you can just [sort the list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/605189/how-can-i-sort-listt-based-on-properties-of-t) afterwards. This allows some flexiblity as well, so you can sort by other fields if you would need to in the future.

```
list.Sort(emp => emp.FirstName); //list would be the list you obtain from the query above.
```

Comment: Yes, that's what I ended up doing. Odd that the ORDER BY won't work in the query, though.

Comment: @JeffCren true, true. I'm not very well-versed in SQLite, but I generally won't sort in the database if I feel like I would need to sort it by other columns afterwards. Not sure if it's a standard, but that's mine :)