# Sort string array in special style

Tags: c#, arrays, sorting

what we need to do if we want to sort our `string Array` in a special form?
 For example we have this:

```
players = new string[12] {"soccer","12","man","swim","3","woman","volleyball","12","man","baseball","13","man"};
```

now we want to sort `Array` by this form:(its just my desire order and don't have any logic)

```
sort = new string[4] {"swim","baseball","volleyball","soccer"}
```

and finally have:

> out = [{swim,3,woman},{baseball,13,man},{volleyball,12,man},{soccer,12,man}]

Comment: Sorry but I don't understand your logic here... Why not create player objects instead?

Comment: what is the logic? why swim comes before baseball? why soccer comes after baseball?

Comment: its not AI there should be some logic for creating collection

Comment: Described behaviour has nothing to do with sorting. Rather it is some kind of mapping which will work only with `players` array having special items order and will not work in any arbitrary case.

Comment: @Mivaweb this array received from a serial string and I convert it to an Array. Now I want to assort it to my order. Is it clear? what's your mean from player objects?

Comment: @EhsanDavoudi by serial string you mean as one single string an then you create and array out of it

Comment: See @Mivaweb's answer. Don't convert it to an array of strings, that's just making life hard. Convert it to a list of player objects instead.

Comment: There is not any logic and I have a form that want to fill it with this order. now I want assort my Array to facilitate it.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking. See the [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) page for help clarifying this question.

Comment: @David Arno may you guide me how? I can understand your mean.

Comment: @EhsanDavoudi, read the answer: it is guiding you.

Comment: @EhsanDavoudi check my answer . If you can't use classes due to some reason.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The other answers make a good point about creating a class to hold your data, but it can be done without it:

```
var ordered = Enumerable.Range(0, players.Length / 3)
.Select(i => new string[] { players[i*3], players[i*3+1], players[i*3+2] })
.OrderBy(a => Array.IndexOf(sort, a[0]))
.ToArray();
```

If you have sports in the players array that are not present in the sort array, you can filter them out.

```
var ordered = (from i in Enumerable.Range(0, players.Length / 3)
let index = Array.IndexOf(sort, players[i*3])
where index >= 0
select new string[] { players[i*3], players[i*3+1], players[i*3+2] }
).OrderBy(a => Array.IndexOf(sort, a[0])).ToArray();
```

Comment: I must say, pretty interesting approach

Comment: good. but my desire Items went in last of my array. In my players list we have some another sport that we don't want show on my result. like `'Chess'`.

Answer (score 3):

You have one big string array which contains all of your player details.
This is not the best solution.

Create player objects which contains all of the properties and put that in an array.

Then you can create custom sorting.

**Player object:**

```
public class Player {
     public string Type { get; set; }
     public string Gender { get; set; }
     public int AmountOfPlayers { get; set; }
     public int Order { get; set; }
}
```

**Create your array list of Player objects:**

```
List<Player> list = new List<Player>();
list.Add(new Player() { Type = "swim", Gender = "women", AmountOfPlayers = 3, Order = 1 });
list.Add(new Player() { Type = "soccer", Gender = "men", AmountOfPlayers = 12, Order = 4 });
list.Add(new Player() { Type = "volleyball", Gender = "men", AmountOfPlayers = 12, Order = 3 });
list.Add(new Player() { Type = "baseball", Gender = "men", AmountOfPlayers = 13, Order = 2 });
```

**Sorting:**

```
var sortedList = list.OrderBy(c => c.Order);
```

Comment: the sort is wrong (he has a specific sorting... swin first, soccer last)... and `OrderBy` isn't inplace... it returns a new sorted `IEnumerable<>`

Comment: @Mivaweb same as **xanatos** said, it's not true. Because after sorting by `Type` we'll not have my desire result.

Comment: List<Players> should be List<Player>

Comment: @EhsanDavoudi you can also set an extra property `Order` to assign the required order of your list. Eg 1 = swim, 2 = baseball, ...

Answer (score 2):

While I would suggest the Object oriented approach as illustrated by others. However just in case due to some reservations you cannot do that then this will work.

```
string[] players = new string[15] {"soccer","12","man","swim","3","woman","volleyball","12","man","baseball","13","man"
    ,"chess","18","man"};
string[] sort = new string[4] {"swim","baseball","volleyball","soccer"};
string[] playersSorted= new string[sort.Length*3];
int destStartIndex = 0;
foreach(string str in sort)
{
  int sourceStartIndex = Array.IndexOf(players,str);
  Array.Copy(players, sourceStartIndex, playersSorted, destStartIndex, 3);
  destStartIndex += 3;
}
```

[DEMO](http://volatileread.com/utilitylibrary/snippetcompiler?id=20687)

Comment: Just be aware that Array.IndexOf is an O(n) operation, where n is the Length of array, if you have only a few sports it's probably fine.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this way. First create a class out of initial `string[]`, which can represent all the values in a format shown below:

```
Class Sport
{
   public string Name {get; set;}
   public int Number {get; set;}
   public string Gender {get; set;}
}
```

Once you have the collection as `List<Sport> sportList`, now you need to create a custom `IComparer` to do the necessary sorting:

```
class SportSorter : IComparer<Sport>
{           
    public int Compare(Sport x, Sport y )
    {
        int retVal = 0;            
        retVal = string.Compare(x.Name,y.Name);
        return retVal;
    }
}
```

Now simply you can call by using the instance of `SportSorter`

```
SportSorter ss = new SportSorter();

sportList.Sort(ss);
```

Please note right now I am using `Name` property to Sort, same can be changed in `CustomSorter (IComparer)` code. This is a stable version of sort as compared to `OrderBy`, which use `QuickSort`. In case you want to chain multiple sorters in different directions together then check the following response:

[Sort List of Dictionary using IComparer instead of OrderBy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31057258/sort-list-of-dictionary-using-icomparer-instead-of-orderby)

Also using the `Sort` in place of `OrderBy` will ensure sorting the same memory, not creating a new list as done by `OrderBy`

Answer (score 1):

**Code copied from Mivaweb:**

```
public class Player {
     public string Type { get; set; }
     public string Gender { get; set; }
     public int AmountOfPlayers { get; set; }
}
```

Then

```
List<Player> list = new List<Player>();
list.Add(new Player() { Type = "swim", Gender = "women", AmountOfPlayers = 3 });
```

**My code:**

```
public static readonly string[] Order = new string[4] {"swim","baseball","volleyball","soccer"};

public static int OrderOf(string str)
{
    int ix = Array.IndexOf(Order, str);
    if (ix == -1)
    {
        ix = int.MaxValue;
    }
    return ix;
}
```

Then sort it:

```
list.Sort((p, q) => OrderOf(p.Type).CompareTo(OrderOf(q.Type)));
```

the `list.Sort()` is "in place", so it changes directly the `list`. Note that if sports different from the one in the lsit are present, they will go in the first places of the ordered list.

The `OrderOf` uses the `Array.IndexOf` to find the index of a type of sport in the `Order` array. Unknown types of sport go last.

Answer (score 1):

This is not any sort actually but still if you want to process this data you can use following approach which is not good approach though.

```
string[,] outArray = new string[sort.Length, 3];
        for (int i = 0; i < sort.Length; i++)
        {
            int pos = Array.IndexOf(players, sort[i]);
            outArray[i, 0] = players[pos];
            outArray[i, 1] = players[pos + 1];
            outArray[i, 2] = players[pos + 2];
        }
```

Use objects,collections and lambda / LINQ for efficient solution and I guess all of the above answers follow the better approach.